# really possible to transfer the camera control with unity on swift?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, avcapturesession

The question is, is it really possible to transfer the camera control with unity, namely the AR Session for the mobile developer? so that it can capture the stream from the camera , because on ios you can't create two sessions for working with one camera